# How can I re-write this function's comparisons and methods for better efficiency?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a function which runs about 30-40 times which helps me add a certain class to some layouts I have, if conditions are met. Unfortunately, it has proved itself a bit of a hog for the phone's CPU:

```
function addClassOnRequirement(target_div, target_div_unpacked, class_to_add, cols) {

    var len_list = $(target_div).length;

    // If layout has 2 columns
    if(cols === 2) {
        // If the layout has an odd number of items, add the said class.
        if (len_list % 2 === 1) {
            $(target_div_unpacked).addClass(class_to_add);
        }
        // If layout has 3 columns
    } else if(cols === 3) {
        // If the layout's number of items (3 on each row) has the number ~5 or so
        // add this class. If 2 rows, 3 items on first row, 2  items on 
        // second row exist, there
        // should be 6, so add this class to do some CSS jumble since 
        // they're 5.
        if (((len_list - 2) % 3) === 0) {
            $(target_div_unpacked).addClass(class_to_add);
        }
    }
}
```

**target_div** represents the selector for the `<ul>` of the layout.

**target_div_unpacked** represents the "pure" selector, without tags such as "ul"

**class_to_add** represents the name of the class to be added to target_div_unpacked

**cols** represents the number of cols I have to add.

All of which are hard-coded and are not generated from other functions, exactly like this:

```
addClassOnRequirement(".posts-layout3 li", ".posts-layout3", "col-3-last2-child-50-width", 3);
```

In a layout where it has to get the length of a big `<ul>` with lots of childs, such as:

```
<ul class="layout-to-test">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ..
    ..
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

The situation gets worse, because it has to iterate through it all, get the length, etc.

Here's what I followed for optimization:

- Use if - else if because there are only two cases, with exact
  non-range cases. (switch for 3-10 cases).
- Use subtraction instead of addition

Unfortunately, it seems that regardless of this, the function still clogs. How can I improve?

Comment: cache your jquery selectors `$(target_div_unpacked)` or move it to pure javascript: `var element = document.querySelector(target_div_unpacked)`

Comment: What exactly is `target_div` and  `target_div_unpacked`?  Could you add an example via snippet ?

Comment: If you are looking for a simplification, just use `var len_list = $(target_div).length; if ((len_list + 1) % col === 0) $(target_div_unpacked).addClass(class_to_add);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if i understand your question correctly, but this function should be adding the classes to a container if it has a certain number of children matching the `childSelector`. And it should be performant too.

```js
// add  some lists to the dom
function setUp(lists, elementsPerList) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for(var i = 0; i < lists; ++i) {
    let list = document.createElement('ul');
    list.classList.add('test-layout');
    for(var j = 0; j < elementsPerList; ++j) {
      var element = document.createElement('li');
      element.textContent = 'list item ' + i + '.' + j;
      list.appendChild(element);
    }
    fragment.appendChild(list);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(fragment);
}
setUp(200, 11);
// add a button to run the function
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() { addClassOnRequirement('li', '.test-layout', 'test', 3) })
// relevant part
function addClassOnRequirement(childSelector, containerSelector, klass, cols) {
    if(cols !== 2 && cols !== 3) return;
    var containers  = document.querySelectorAll(containerSelector);

    for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; ++i) {   
      var container = containers[i];
      var children = container.querySelectorAll(childSelector);
      if(children.length % cols !== 0) {
        container.classList.add(klass);
      }
    }
}
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
```

Comment: This is crazy performant. From 0.8-1ms to 0.2 ms consistent (only the main function). Can you please explain a bit what your thought process was?

Comment: First thing i thought: "Get rid of jQuery, because it has poor performance when not used  correctly". Second thought: "Cache the `querySelectorAll` results as soon as possible to prevent calling them too much".  That's all. This could be done more performant, but it would require more deep  knowledge about browser "reflow" and  "repaints", selector speed and memory management.

Comment: Amazing. Can you explain the thought behind [].slice.call? What exactly does it help me with in this context? Also, do you have any good links for writing good, efficient Javascript?

Comment: The idea behind `[].slice.call` can be found [**here**](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array). In this case you won't even need it. I removed it for this case.

Comment: I changed the code  a bit to add the class if the length of the last row of elements doesn't match the `col` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that you want special rules depending on whether you have one too few list items in a multi-column list?

If so the most efficient way to solve this would be without javascript at all. You can solve this with css:

```css
.three-col-list li {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.three-col-list li:nth-child(3n + 2):nth-last-child(1) {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<p>List 1</p>
<ul class="three-col-list">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>

<p>List 2</p>
<ul class="three-col-list">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>

<p>List 3</p>
<ul class="three-col-list">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ABORT. This actually works when there are 6 elements. Can you pretty please explain where the "only if 5 elements are here, do this" part?

Comment: Are you sure it affects 6 elements? The way it should work is `:nth-child(3n + 2)` only targets the 2nd, 5th, 8th, and so on element while `:nth-last-child(1)` only targets the last element. So the last element has to be the 2nd, 5th, 8th etc element.